# What is jstcache and why it is being added to my HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

While using Firebug, I have noticed an attribute name `jstcache` is added to some of my html tags, while it is not visible in the source of the page. In Firebug I see following

```
<html lang="en" jstcache="0">
  <head>
  <body jstcache="0">
  <div class="mydiv" jstcache="0">
    ....
```

I google result shows it is related to [JSTemplate](https://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/wiki/HowToUseJsTemplate), I am not using it and I do not know why it is being added to my code?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue and in my app I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API. When the google map is initialized, I noticed the "jstcache" attributes are applied to all parent DOM elements of the map. When I disable the map feature, "jstcache" attributes are no longer added. Unfortunately, I can't explain why this is happening though. Perhaps someone can shed some light on this. I have not been able to find any documentation.

Answer (score 27):

It seems it's jsTemplate:

https://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/wiki/HowToUseJsTemplate

All the tags are of the style jstXXX.

jstcache=0 is just saying 'don't store this page in the browser's cache'.

Answer (score 4):

jstcache is automatically added when js-template is used.

**Now what is js-template ?**

js-template is a powerful browser-side templating framework for jQuery + HTML5. It is an updated and modernized reincarnation of Google's excellent open-source JsTemplate project.

You can find more here

> https://github.com/toddfast/js-template

Answer (score 3):

These attributes are added by Javascript after the page loads, so you won't see them in the source tab.

It is very likely that this is due to some Firefox extension you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript templating (js template) is a fast and efficient technique to render client-side templates with JavaScript using a JSON data source. The template is HTML markup, peppered with tags that will either insert variables or run programming logic.;]

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the script tags while loading through the *http* pipeline are exposed to **spidey** protocol filters and this is added to ensure that it is executed with appropriate protocol so that it remains accessible

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the width and height attributes in iframe, this will embed the map with a default size and without the jstcache

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33429843)